# Installing R Text Mining package on Ubuntu Lucid

Tags: r, text-mining

New to R, and am trying to install the text mining package (tm). However when I do

> > install.packages("tm",dependencies=TRUE)

I get the following error:

```
  Warning in install.packages("tm", dependencies = TRUE) :
  argument 'lib' is missing: using '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library'
  --- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
  Loading Tcl/Tk interface ... done
  Warning message:
  In getDependencies(pkgs, dependencies, available, lib) :
  package ‘tm’ is not available
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a thread on this in the [Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1644889).

Most likely answer is that tm requires a more recent version of R (>= 2.11.0) than the one that you have installed. Try adding an R repository as [described here](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README) and upgrading, then try to install tm again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, that is exactly what I was trying. I updated by Ubuntu repositories, re-installed (newer version of) R and then installed tm as described above. Everything worked great.